# Вывод None, хотя там его не должно быть

Tags: python, bitcoin

Коротко вот такой код:

```
from bitcoinlib.wallets import Wallet, wallet_delete

def o():
    w = Wallet.create(Name, keys=passphrase, network='bitcoin')
    pipo = w.info()
    print(pipo)
o()
```

при print(pipo) выводит none. Через return я пробовал, не получилось. Мне нужно что бы оно в "pipo" сохранило информацию.

Comment: *Не ответ, но, по-моему, полезная информация.* Это по-вашему не должно быть None, но если бы почитали документацию, https://bitcoinlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/bitcoinlib.wallets.html#bitcoinlib.wallets.Wallet.info то стало бы ясно, что ничего, кроме `None` там нельзя ожидать. Этот метод ничего не возвращает, а сразу делает `print` в stdout. У вас же в консоли выводится что-нибудь, кроме `None`? Признайтесь:) А что-бы сохранить это в переменную, придется как-то перехватывать вывод и все получается гораздо сложнее, чем казалось ранее.

Answer (score 1):

Вам двойка за отсутствие желания решить проблему.

Вот на выбор:

```
pipo = w.as_dict()
pipo = w.as_json()
```

Наверняка, ещё что-нибудь похожее есть. Лениво в документации читать.